# Are unsaturated fats antioxidants?

Tags: biochemistry, lipids

Unsaturated fats contain double bonds like carotenoids (which is an antioxidant), and from my understanding, what makes carotenoid an antioxidant is that its double bonds allow it to undergo oxidation, hence they can donate electrons to free radicals. Therefore, would this suggest unsaturated fats (especially those with more double bonds) are also antioxidants?